# Table BBCode with Xenforo

Tags: bbcode, xenforo

I'm using Xenforo for my forum website, it is [Rao Vat](http://raovat99.com)

I meet a problem here is I cannot view the table in my post, I found some plug in for xenforo to do this, but I don't like using them because I want to change the code.

Does anyone have experience or suggestion for me on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Just an update!

With the newest update to XenForo 2.1 adding tables is now possible. When posting a thread or post the option is now there to add a table.

Answer (score 0):

XenForo does not have built-in table functionality in the editor. If you want to use tables, third party add-ons are your only option.

There's several available:

[CTA Table BB Codes (free)](https://xenforo.com/community/resources/cta-table-bb-code.2847/)

[Brivium Advanced Table BB Code (Paid)](https://xenforo.com/community/resources/brivium-advanced-table-bbcode.2283/)

[Datatables BB Code by Waindigo](https://xenforo.com/community/resources/datatables-bb-code-by-waindigo.2375/)